# Python backup the file with last modified date within 6 months

Tags: python, automation, window, backup

I am new python learner, I am doing backup automation with python. However, I would like to only backup the file with last modified date within 6 months, how can I type in python ? Many Thanks !!!!!

Comment: Do you want to get all files or specific folder?

Comment: I mean I only need need the code for doing the date condition only, because I can't figure out how to do that part... thanks!! @suman

Comment: You should you os module to do that.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know the next step ? Like how can I make a condition on it ? Would you mind to type your code here ? Thanks

Comment: do you have TeamViewer. I tell you how to write it

Comment: I don't have, sorry ... is it possible to type that part here ?

Comment: Please check it's work or not. I write to you. It gets the list of the file was changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import datetime as dt

now = dt.datetime.now()
ago = now-dt.timedelta(days=180)

for root, dirs,files in os.walk('.'):  
    for fname in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, fname)
        st = os.stat(path)    
        mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
        if mtime > ago:
            print('%s modified %s'%(path, mtime))
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Hi, I think it's not work, it does print the last modified date out, but it does not filter it, because I want to back up the file within 6 months only, grater than 6 months no need to back up, wondering do u know how to fix it ? Thanks Suman !!

Comment: Yes give me 10 mintute.